# Align and format table

Tags: tables

I have these two tables:

[image]

I want that the first table (descarga de recursos) aligned with the second table (ver boletines)

I tried to do the tables with online editors like http://truben.no/table/ but I can't find and optimal result.
'Cause for cells with multiple lines, only the first row is in the right place, the rest of rows passed to the other column.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{figure}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Nombre: & Descarga de recursos \\ \hline

Descripción: & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Este caso de uso establece la posibilidad de descargar \\los recursos relacionados con un boletín de información \\publicado en un grupo abierto o cerrado\end{tabular} \\ \hline

Pre-condición: & Que halla un recurso disponible para descargar \\ \hline

Pos-condición: & Descarga de un recurso adjunto a un boletín de información \\ \hline

Flujo primario: & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Inicia sesión de estudiante, ingresar al grupo, \\descargar recurso.\end{tabular} \\ \hline

Flujo secundario: & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}No se puede acceder a la cuenta, se interrumpe el proceso, \\el grupo ha sido cerrado o no existe, el archivo no \\existe o esta corrupto \end{tabular} \\ \hline

Actores: & Estudiante \\ \hline

Inclusión y/o extensión: & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} - Inclusión: Recurso para descarga en boletín o noticia publicada. \\ - Opcional: N.H.  \end{tabular} \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|} 
\hline
Nombre: & Ver boletines \\ \hline

Descripción: & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Este caso de uso establece la posibilidad de ver \\los boletines de información \\publicados en un grupo abierto o cerrado\end{tabular} \\ \hline

Pre-condición: & Que halla un boletin disponible para ver. \\ \hline

Pos-condición: & Ser informado respecto a un boletín publicado. \\ \hline

Flujo primario: & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Inicia sesión de estudiante, ingresar al grupo, \\ver boletín.\end{tabular} \\ \hline

Flujo secundario: & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}No se puede acceder a la cuenta, se interrumpe el proceso, \\el grupo ha sido cerrado o no existe, el boletín no \\existe o no ha sido publicado aún. \end{tabular} \\ \hline

Actores: & Estudiante \\ \hline

Inclusión y/o extensión: & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}  - Inclusión:     Boletines o     noticias publicadas. \\ - Opcional: N.H.  \end{tabular} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: What do you mean with align? Also, why aren't you using the `p` column type? Your MWE is not complete. Welcome to TeX.SX

Comment: I want both tables have the same size ( the second table size). I tried to use $p$ type, but with this table out of the sheet.

Answer (score 4):

With normal p-columns:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{showframe}
% do not load graphicx twice, load babel more in the beginning and hyperref at last

\begin{document}
\begin{center} % better use a table here, but I do not know your setup  
    \begin{tabular}{lp{7.7cm}}
        \toprule
        Nombre: & Descarga de recursos \\ \midrule      
        Descripción: & Este caso de uso establece la posibilidad de descargar los recursos relacionados con un boletín de información publicado en un grupo abierto o cerrado. Este caso de uso establece la posibilidad de descargar los recursos relacionados con un boletín de información publicado en un grupo abierto o cerrado\\ 
        Pre-condición: & Que halla un recurso disponible para descargar \\ 
        Pos-condición: & Descarga de un recurso adjunto a un boletín de información \\ 
        Flujo primario: & Inicia sesión de estudiante, ingresar al grupo, descargar recurso. \\ 
        Flujo secundario: & No se puede acceder a la cuenta, se interrumpe el proceso, el grupo ha sido cerrado o no existe, el archivo no existe o esta corrupto  \\ 
        Actores: & Estudiante \\
        Inclusión y/o extensión: &  - Inclusión: Recurso para descarga en boletín o noticia publicada. \par - Opcional: N.H. \\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\begin{center}  
    \begin{tabular}{lp{7.7cm}}
        \toprule
        Nombre: & Ver boletines \\ \midrule     
        Descripción: & Este caso de uso establece la posibilidad de ver los boletines de información publicados en un grupo abierto o cerrado \\ 
        Pre-condición: & Que halla un boletin disponible para ver. \\ 
        Pos-condición: & Ser informado respecto a un boletín publicado. \\ 
        Flujo primario: & Inicia sesión de estudiante, ingresar al grupo, ver boletín. \\
        Flujo secundario: & No se puede acceder a la cuenta, se interrumpe el proceso, el grupo ha sido cerrado o no existe, el boletín no existe o no ha sido publicado aún.  \\
        Actores: & Estudiante \\
        Inclusión y/o extensión: & - Inclusión: Boletines o noticias publicadas. \par - Opcional: N.H. \\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In order to find a good value for the p-column, I load the package `showframe` and do the adjustment manually.

I suggested that the first column is having the same width all the time. If the text changes here between tabulars, you may use `{p{}p{}}` for the column specification.

Answer (score 2):

Here is MWE using `tabularx`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{figure}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|}
\hline
Nombre: & Descarga de recursos \\ \hline

Descripción: & Este caso de uso establece la posibilidad de descargar los recursos relacionados con un boletín de información publicado en un grupo abierto o cerrado. Este caso de uso establece la posibilidad de descargar los recursos relacionados con un boletín de información publicado en un grupo abierto o cerrado\\ \hline
Nombre: & Descarga de recursos \\ \hline

Descripción: & Este caso de uso establece la posibilidad de descargar los recursos relacionados con un boletín de información publicado en un grupo abierto o cerrado. Este caso de uso establece la posibilidad de descargar los recursos relacionados con un boletín de información publicado en un grupo abierto o cerrado\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|}
\hline
Nombre: & Descarga de recursos \\ \hline

Descripción: & Este caso de uso establece la posibilidad de descargar los recursos relacionados con un boletín de información publicado en un grupo abierto o cerrado. Este caso de uso establece la posibilidad de descargar los recursos relacionados con un boletín de información publicado en un grupo abierto o cerrado\\ \hline
Nombre: & Descarga de recursos \\ \hline

Descripción: & Este caso de uso establece la posibilidad de descargar los recursos relacionados con un boletín de información publicado en un grupo abierto o cerrado. Este caso de uso establece la posibilidad de descargar los recursos relacionados con un boletín de información publicado en un grupo abierto o cerrado\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```